# Class Design, populate instance of class

Tags: c#, class

I want to validate my class design principals.

If I have a class Car, and I have a public method GetCarByID(int id).

First I need to call the Car constructor to get an instance of the car.

```
Car MyCar = new Car();
```

then I can call GetCarByID() to populate the instance of the car.

```
MyCar.GetCarByID(123);
```

MyCar should now be a populated instance of the Car class?  Is this the proper use of a class?  Then when I want to save my car (for example back to a database) I can create another method for save() and call.

```
MyCar.Save();
```

Can someone please validate or correct me if I'm thinking about class design in a wrong way? Is this a specific coding pattern, if so what one?

Comment: Design questions are usually opinion based... How big you app - as you design is probably ok for 3-5Kloc app. Bigger you'd probably want split serialization completely from `Car` object.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line actually creates an instance of a `Car`:

`Car myCar = new Car()`

It sounds like you may want a public *static* method in the Car class called `GetCarByID(int ID)` which can take an ID and return the car instance represented by that ID. A possible implementation could be as follows:

```
public static Car GetCarByID(int id)
{
    // Search a list of cars by ID, and return it
}
```

And you would want to add all created cars to some static list in the Car class, potentially in the main Car constructor.

Alternatively, you could use a factory, where you do as follows:

```
public static Car CreateCarByID(int id)
{
    // Create a car with the given ID (using a private constructor) and return it
    Car myCar = new Car(id);
    return myCar;
}

private Car(int id)
{
    // Save ID to field
}
```

Comment: From what I know, you really shouldn't create static methods to access data, they should be a part of the class?

Comment: This would be a static method inside of the `Car` class, that you could use to search and retrieve *previously made* cars by ID.

Comment: @TravisK: This static method is what's called a "factory method" and is a perfectly acceptable way of instantiating an object.  If the object creation logic becomes more complex, or if you have valid reasons for avoiding static methods and want to maintain objects (testability, for example), then you can create a "factory object" (`CarFactory`) whose job is to build and return instances of this object.

Comment: @TravisK, you are correct; good practice is to only use static methods for "pure functions", ie ones that act on the data passed to them and return a result without any side-effects or reading of "state" data.

Comment: @TravisK, this answer is an example of using a service locator pattern, which is widely regarded as an anti-pattern these days as it makes writing tests much harder than they need to be.

Comment: The first example is just a way to retrieve Cars from a static list by ID, call the pattern what you will. The second example is a simple factory where you create by ID. You would generally do this if you wanted to do something else in that factory such as store the data.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an advised approach. When you instantiate an instance of the class, the instance should be completely usable. When you call the constructor, you pass in the necessary arguments to create the instance successfully. You shouldn't be calling methods after construction to complete the "population" of the instance. The reason being someone might assume the `Car` instance is usable before the call to `GetCarByID` has been made resulting in all sorts of headaches/maintainability issues, especially for other developers.

E.g.:

```
Car MyCar = new Car("123");
```

where constructor:

```
public Car(string ID)
{
   _id = ID;
}
```

Comment: It's worth adding to your answer that `Car.Save` is a bad idea too as it fails to adopt separation of concerns. The `Car` class should worry about modelling a car; another class should worry about loading/saving from/to a database.

Comment: In your example would data access code (for example to get the car from a database) be included in the public Car(string ID) constructor?

Comment: That would be the responsibility of the class aggregated/composed of Car objects, not the Car itself.The Car instance should only ever be composed of lower level objects of itself (e.g. engine, wheels, doors etc.), not "itself", that is the responsibility of the containing class, e.g. "Factory" or "Car Plant" etc.